# How do I ensure that my media query sidebar nav closes without affect my main nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my max-width:320px media query I have a sidebar navigation as oppose to the regular normal bar that is in the other max-width's. now the problem I'm experiencing is that every time I close my sidebar nav in max-width:320px. the regular menu in the largest width:1440px is removed because the browser's element style is set to "display:none". How do I get around this, close my sidebar nav without removing main nav in the other width?

so guys I've dynamically added another class on my navbar element to use it for 320px max-width query but it's still exhibiting the same behaviour. I'm totally lost now.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mynavbar").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mynavbar").style.display = "none";
}

var nav = document.queryselect('#myNavbar')
nav = classList.add('nav-remove')
nav = classList.add('navbar')
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 91px;
  width: 1094px !important;
  left: 152px;
  top: 46px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .nav-remove {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .nav-remove a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-remove a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: block;
    z-index: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mynavbar" class="navbar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="{% static 'TheMachine Images/The Machine 2.png' %}" alt="">
  </div>
  <span class="HOME">HOME</span>
  <span class="ARTIST">ARTIST</span>
  <span class="ABOUTUS">ABOUT US</span>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <textarea name="" placeholder="Search" id="search-area" cols="16" rows="1"></textarea>
    <div class="search-icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rec">
    <span class="SignIn">SignIN</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rec2">
    <span class="SignUP">SignUp</span>
  </div>
  <span class="nav-menu" style="font-size: 17px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;OPEN</span>


</div>
```

Comment: Do not manipulate CSS properties directly, but add/remove a class to/from your navbar element dynamically. Then you can write selectors in your CSS, that make this class only have the effect of hiding the navbar within specific media queries ...

Comment: I'm relatively new in JavaScript. I'd appreciate if you could show an example.

Comment: Where is the problem? Don't know how to add/remove a class? Then research it please, anything but a new topic. And then you just need to write rules in your stylesheet, that hide the navbar, when it has that particular class - and wrap those into appropriate media queries, so that it only gets hidden in the resolutions you want. `#mynavbar.foobar { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

the mistake that I was making was that since the original website is 1440px. I didn't do a media query for it and was expecting the original css to take effect and override the 320px media query but the browser instead was prioritizing the query. its when I properly looked at the other queries (different width's) and saw that since I had locked in the 'display:block!important' property. I wasn't experiencing this problem. so I went back and created a query for 1440px for it to take priority over the 320px.

this is the original css

```
.navbar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1098px;
    height: 91px;
    left: 185px;
    top: 37px;
}
```

this is the 320px media query

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:420px){
.navbar{
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
}
```

as you can see I've changed the navbar to be a sidebar nav that requires opening & closing. which is where the problem began.

this is how I fixed it. I added a query for 1440px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .navbar{
        display: block !important;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1098px;
        height: 91px;
        left: 185px;
        top: 37px;  
    }
}
```